# Обособление однородных и неоднородных определений

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

"У него были черные маленькие, как бусинки, глаза". Здесь будет ставиться запятая? Если да, то эти определения объединяются понятием  "внешний вид"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**У него были черные, маленькие, как бусинки, глаза.**

Да, это однородные определения, они обозначают сближенные понятия (общая тема ―  описанию внешности).

С другой стороны, при наличии сравнительного оборота, отнесенного **ко второму прилагательному**,  здесь **приходится** ставить запятую между определениями, чтобы разделить их.

Comment: А возможен вариант без запятой при определениях  в этом случае?

Comment: У него были маленькие черные глаза. Здесь гораздо лучше не ставить, чем ставить.

Comment: При отсутствии сравнительного оборота запятую можно не ставить, ведь прилагательные обозначают разные признаки. Такие задачи решаются в контексте. Например: У него были черные, маленькие, очень живые глаза... здесь сближение признаков, запятые ставятся. У него были маленькие черные глаза и коротко стриженные волосы. Здесь запятая не нужна.